# Advice on Custom Font

Tags: fonts

I have been designing a online survey with a generic platform for the last week, it is due to go out today.

The survey platform assured us that the required custom files were going to be uploaded to their server for our use, and this hasn't happened.

I am trying to figure out where I can store the files, to then use `@font-face`, however this is a topic that I struggle with.

Our own website is hosted with WordPress, I cannot upload files onto the survey platforms server and I have tried dropbox (not sure if this was a silly idea, but thought it might work) which would not work.

Does anyone have an idea on where I could store the files, would a cloud based storage platform work?

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve your problem.  Just a bit of advice - In the future when writing your question, include example code, what you have tried (specifically), in as much detail as you can provide so that someone who doesn't know anything about what you are doing, is able to give you assistance. "website hosted with WordPress" and "generic survey script" are too vague.